# IE 8 rendering font-face normal as italic

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I have been pondering for quite some time on what causes some IE versions to render @font-face fonts as italic, even though the styles are declared as normal.

My main thought is that IE won't download every font-file before rendering the page.

In my CSS I have declared font files for different typefaces of the same font - ranging from thin italic to ultra. They are all declared using the same setup:

```
@font-face { /* THIN ITALIC */
    font-family: Unit;
    src: url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-ThinIta.eot")
    src: url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-ThinIta.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-ThinIta.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic, oblique;
    font-variant: normal;
}
```

through

```
@font-face { /* ULTRA */
    font-family: Unit;
    src: url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-Ultra.eot");
    src: url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-Ultra.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-Ultra.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
}
```

As you can see, italics are declared as `font-style: italic, oblique;`, while normal is declared as `font-style: normal;`.

Now, to the rendering.

[This is how IE 9 renders it](http://ta-kundesenter.no/bilder/font_ie9.jpg)

[This is how IE 8 renders it every now and then](http://ta-kundesenter.no/bilder/font_ie8.jpg)

Comment: Looks like what's described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3795632/893780): IE8 will only use the first @font-face declaration for a given font family.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link, robertklep! I'll try putting the normal declaration first to see if it will look somewhat descent :)

Comment: It doesn't seem consistent, though, @robertklep.

[IE 8 rendering normal as both normal and italic](http://ta-kundesenter.no/bilder/font_ie8_2.jpg)

The italic rendering in this screendump has a different font-weight than those rendering as normal.

Answer (score 2):

Posted as answer is this SO question: [Custom font sometimes renders in italics in IE8 / IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390511/custom-font-sometimes-renders-in-italics-in-ie8-ie7)

---

You need to create a custom name for each of your @font-face font-family. e.g.

```
@font-face { /* THIN ITALIC */
   font-family: UnitItalic;
   src: url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-ThinIta.eot")
   src: url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-ThinIta.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-ThinIta.woff") format("woff");
   font-weight: 100;
   font-style: italic, oblique;
   font-variant: normal;
}


@font-face { /* THIN ITALIC */
   font-family: UnitNormal;
   src: url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-ThinIta.eot")
   src: url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-ThinIta.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../gfx/fonts/UnitWeb-ThinIta.woff") format("woff");
   font-weight: 100;
   font-style: italic, oblique;
   font-variant: normal;
}
```