# Can a single font style defined in <body> produce other font styles when the content is edited?

Tags: css, font-face

Let's say that I'm using a non-system font (ex., PT Sans) for a CMS website. So what I do is, I'll include the font family of different styles (say, Regular, Italic and Bold) using @font-face. Then I would define the font-family of `body` as `PT Sans Regular`. All is well till now.
Then, my client for example, edits some text content in the website. He gives different font-styles to the text - like he *boldens* an important message and *italicizes* the name of locations. So altogether, he stylizes the content the way he likes. No problem with that too.
But, what the real question is, how will the website know that **if** there's a italicized text, it should use `PT Sans Italic` instead of the regular version of the font, even if the `body's` font is `PT Sans Regular`?

I've been thinking about this for a while, but I can't find a solution for it.
Is there a possible solution for situations like this?

Comment: The CMS shouldn't be determining fonts, the site's template and stylesheet should. Things like bold an italics are not font-dependent.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-define-bold-italic-using-font-face

Comment: So is your question, what font does a browser use if the non-standard font I specify has no italics?

Comment: @j08691 - Quite. But I believe it's more like the link provided by David.

Comment: @DavidNguyen - So, I have to give the same font-family name to all the (a)font-face, but define the font-style/weight according the font I'm linking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely possible. Here's how you do it:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PTSans';
    src: url('pts55f-webfont.eot');
    src: url('pts55f-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('pts55f-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('pts55f-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('pts55f-webfont.svg#PTSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'PTSans';
    src: url('pts56f-webfont.eot');
    src: url('pts56f-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('pts56f-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('pts56f-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('pts56f-webfont.svg#PTSansItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'PTSans';
    src: url('pts75f-webfont.eot');
    src: url('pts75f-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('pts75f-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('pts75f-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('pts75f-webfont.svg#PTSansBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'PTSans';
    src: url('pts76f-webfont.eot');
    src: url('pts76f-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('pts76f-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('pts76f-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('pts76f-webfont.svg#PTSansBoldItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;

}
```

When you define the @font-face fonts, make sure that all your `font-family` names are the same. Then set the `font-weight` and `font-style` correctly for each font. So if a font is bold, set `font-weight: bold`. etc.

Then in your CSS you can do:

```
body {
    font-family: 'PTSans';
}
```

And the various tags `<strong>` `<em>` etc will pick the correct font that matches.