# CSS Cross browser Font support - bold and italics not working

Tags: css

I have a page which requires use of non-default fonts, and not everyone has these fonts, so I am using the cross browser font trick with CSS. Code is this

```
@font-face {
            font-family: 'Bebas';
            src: url('Bebas.eot');
            src: local('Bebas'), 
                 local('Bebas'), 
                 url('Bebas.ttf') format('truetype'),
                 url('Bebas.svg#font') format('svg'); 
        }
```

Now this code works perfectly with all different fonts I have tried, so I was very happy with it. My problem however is that if I try to make the text bold or italics, it doesn't work unless the font is installed. Is there anyway to get around this? Or this is a limitation with cross browser font support?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-define-bold-italic-using-font-face

Comment: @AdamM it might help if you added specific details as to which browsers it works in and which browsers it doesn't.

Comment: The bold and italics feature does not seem to work in any browser which is my problem. The font itself works perfectly

Comment: @AdamM Actually adam if you see the link Xaisoft commented up there, there is an answer to your question. Create several copies of your font file, one for each style, and then load them all with font-face

Comment: That link works perfectly for fonts that come with different types, but some of the fonts have it all included like the Bebas font. If I install it, I can use bold and italics, but if I don't, then there is only one font file to refer to. Is there anyway to split a font file up into bold regular italics etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add another @font-face specifying the bold file and set the font-weight property to bold.

Comment: Except some of the font types I have downloaded do not have a bold file, it is all included in one, for example that bebas font I am using. If I install it, bold and italics works fine, but if I uninstall it and then use the CSS technique to get it working, the bold does not work which is annoying

Comment: Then just use the same font file

Comment: Tried that too, no luck unfortunately

Comment: Seems this is the way to do it, will just have to download font files which contain bold.tff regular.tff and italics.ttf

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is something you would considder this but Google has a neat way to add non installed fonts to your website [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts). It's pretty well supported.

Answer (score -2):

wherever you show your content on the site in `HTML` way use `HTML Tag` like `<strong></strong>` for Bold and `<i></i>` for Italic, if its not possible in css

Comment: This is extremely bad form, as presentation should not be mixed with content. CSS should be used for styling

Comment: @JohmDon what would you do if its not support in all browser?

Comment: I suppose you would just have to deal with it.

Comment: see that's not the ans of my question!

Comment: No, that's not the answer you **Want** to hear. Unfortunately, some people will just have to make do