# Helvetica font variation in landscape mode of the ipad

Tags: ipad, css, fonts

I have used helvetica font for iPad app but it is showing different visual appearance in portrait mode and landscape. In portrait mode text is perfect bold but in landscape mode it shows more bolder than usual.

Any Idea??

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
     -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

@font-face {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
            src: url('helvetican.ttf');
        }
    .myclass
    { 
        color: #ffffff;
        font:bold 12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        line-height: 16px;
        width:100%; 
        height:30px;
        overflow: hidden; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need it to be the same, encode the bold weight of the font in addition to the normal weight and specify that for the bold stuff.

That way you are relying on the device's rendering of the font, not the devices rendering of the font with it's own interpretation of how it should be thickened to make it bold.

In your current set up, serving only the one weight, the iPad is forced to guess what bold should look like and I think that's what's causing your problem.

Comment: Check out this answer over here for details on HOW -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-define-bold-italic-using-font-face