# font-face weight

Tags: css, font-face

I am using a purchase font (Museo Sans) for a custom font in an app I am working on. The files given to me when I purchased it contain web font files for different weights: MuseoSans100Regular, MuseoSans300Regular, etc. Is there a way in @font-face to specify the files to use for the different weights so that I can do this:

```
font-family: MuseoSans;
font-weight: 300;
```

Rather than this:

```
font-family: MuseoSans300;
```

Comment: this can be done using js which is highly not recommended.

Comment: I don't think so, I think you'll just have to specify the fonts you have by name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define bold, italic using @font-face](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-define-bold-italic-using-font-face)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you have to specify which file is for which `font-weight` in two different `@font-face` definitions:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MuseoSans';
    src: url('../font/museo_sans_100.woff');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MuseoSans';
    src: url('../font/museo_sans_300.woff');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1, p {
    font-family: MuseoSans;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 300; /* uses museo_sans_300.woff */
}

p {
    font-weight: 100; /* uses museo_sans_100.woff*/
}
```

Comment: I just found out that this question was already answered here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-define-bold-italic-using-font-face