# CSS custom fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have the following font files:

```
Raleway-Bold.ttf
Raleway-ExtraBold.ttf
Raleway-ExtraLight.ttf
Raleway-Heavy.ttf
Raleway-Light.ttf
Raleway-Medium.ttf
Raleway-Regular.ttf
Raleway-SemiBold.ttf
Raleway-Thin.ttf
```

Now i have implemented them in my css like follow:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf');
}

.bold
{
    font-family: "Raleway-bold"; !important;
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf');
}


.extraBold
{
    font-family: "Raleway"; !important;
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-ExtraBold.ttf');
}


.extraLight
{
    font-family: "Raleway"; !important;
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-ExtraLight.ttf');
}


.heavy
{
    font-family: "Raleway"; !important;
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-Heavy.ttf');
}


.light
{
    font-family: "Raleway"; !important;
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-Light.ttf');
}


.medium
{
    font-family: "Raleway"; !important;
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf');
}



.thin
{
    font-family: "Raleway"; !important;
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-Thin.ttf');
}


.semi_bold
{
    font-family: "Raleway"; !important;
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-SemiBold.ttf');
}
```

However when i change the class to `semi_bold` for example nothing changes? so am i implementing them in a wrong way or am i missing something?

**Note** That the first raleway the font-face works fine but it is the rest that doesnt seem to make any changes to my text

Comment: If you remove (or comment out) all other css class definitions, does the .semi_bold work?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/  This link should make things more than clear for you.

Comment: Using only .ttf files won't enable all users of your site to make use of your custom font.
Create multiple versions of your font by using a site like fontsquirl. These also provide the correct implementation example files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define all of your custom fonts in `@font-face` blocks. Only then can you use them in normal styles. Here you have defined `Raleway` only, so those classes which use it (all except `.bold`) will use `Raleway-Regular.ttf`.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway-bold';
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway-semibold';
    src: url('/site/resources/fonts/Raleway-SemiBold.ttf');
}
...

.normal {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
}
.bold {
    font-family: 'Raleway-bold';
}
...
```

Note that you need to define somewhere that ordinary text should use `font-family: 'Raleway';`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare each typeface (here, each font weight) in a `@font-face` rule of its own. You should also use different font formats to cover all browsers. For a simple example for the former principle, see [font-face weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462407/font-face-weight) and for the latter, use e.g. the [FontSquirrel generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).