# CSS: How to set a fallback for bold font families?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family, woff

I am using an own custom font which I embed like this:

```
@font-face{font-family:myFont;src:url(css/fonts/myFont.woff);}
@font-face{font-family:myBoldFont;src:url(css/fonts/myBoldFont.woff);}
```

So, when ever I want to use bold font, I do:

```
<style>
.bold{
    font-family:"myBoldFont";
}
</style>
<div class="bold">Hello world</div>
```

Also, I need to overwrite all css definitions that use bold typography by default:

```
<style>
    strong,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8{
        font-family:"myBoldFont";
        font-weight:normal;
    }
</style>
```

As you can see, I must set `font-weight:normal` because if I'd set `font-weight:bold` the browser would not find the right font and do a fallback because there is no definition for "bold" in this .woff file.

So, this works quite well for browsers that do support `@font-face` and .woff files. For browsers that do not, like e.g. older iOS devices, I need to set a fall-back like this:

```
font-family:"myBoldFont",helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
```

So, the fallback to helvetica works, **but** the text is not bold, because `font-weight:normal` is set.

Now, here is the problem:

- If I set `font-weight:bold` then browsers that can handle woff files
  will fall back to a default font instead of using the one I defined
  via the woff file.
- If I set `font-weight:normal` then older browsers that cannot handle
  woff files won't be able to print text bold.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following : [How to add multiple font files for the same font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-define-bold-italic-using-font-face) ?

The `@font-face` property allows you to specify for which styles to apply the font.

Comment: Dang, that's it. I just found that question the moment you posted :-)

Comment: please provide example