# How to merge fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, truetype

I have a number of fonts,

- OpenSans-bold.ttf
- OpenSans-boldItalic.ttf
- OpenSans-extrabold.ttf
- OpenSans-italic.ttf
- OpenSans-light.ttf

How would I go on about to just create one file, as oppose to this many different files?
And perhaps use them on CSS like I would normally, or like you would on photoshop?

e.g.

```
small{font-family:"OpenSans"; font-weight: normal;}
strong{font-family:"OpenSans"; font-weight: bold;}
h2 {font-family:"OpenSans"; font-weight: bolder;}
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: font-strech is not supported in most browsers, and that's not a duplicate, don't know why this question should be closed or voted to close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add multiple font files for the Same Font?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-add-multiple-font-files-for-the-same-font)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to combine multiple fonts in one file is to encode them in base64 and embed them in CSS. They will still be *different* fonts though and the total size will increase. There are various online tools that can create the css for font files you upload, like [this one](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

Comment: well using BASE64 isn't a good idea since the font will never be cached...so you gain nothing, and actually you make things worse, because every time your CSS changed, it will force the user to download the font again. BTW that online tool only lets you merge up to 3 files.

Comment: Just a thought... We can combine fonts into special fonts.css that will be separated from other CSS of site. So if you change (add/remove) fonts than only fonts.css should be reloaded.

Answer (score 12):

You need the different font files if you wish to use different typefaces (regular, italic, bold, etc.), because each typeface is implemented as a separate font file (actually, you even need it in different font formats, to cover different browsers).

But you *can* use them as a single font family, much like you use, say, just Arial and apply italics and bolding to it, using CSS directly or indirectly (via HTML, e.g. `h2` elements are bold by default). For this, you need to *declare* a font family.

E.g., FontSquirrel generates CSS code that defines each typeface as a font family. This is possible, but illogical and inconvenient. For example, it generates

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansbold';
    src: url('opensans-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-bold-webfont.svg#open_sansbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

To make things more logical, change the `font-weight` value, and change the `font-family` name to one that you use in different `@font-face` rules (for the different typefaces of the family). E.g.,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('opensans-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-bold-webfont.svg#open_sansbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: this is the way I am doing it at the moment, but the fonts which was passed on to me added up to 2.8mb which is a lot. hence why I asked if I could somehow manage to merge font's and use them as a normal font instead of as separate font.

Comment: The normal way of using fonts is that each typeface is a font file of its own. It would not save space to combine them into one file, and besides, that’s not how font technology works.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Adding a italic or bold property to a font-family is not always same as downloading a separate font. As an example, please check Roboto from Google Web Fonts. Just adding a font-weight of 900 to Roboto-Regular does not make it same as Roboto-Black.

Comment: @ChrisOdney it is the same when it is set up correctly, as this example does. google fonts does this in their link element font face call: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900 declaring roboto-regular and robot-black font-family names seems like where this is confusing.