# Change CSS "bold" property font-weight value

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The question is pretty straightforward.

I use Bootstrap, where all the bold things are CSSized in

```
tag {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

but I use `Open Sans` (as so many people), where `font-weight: 400` is not enough and `font-weight: 700` is much better.

Is there a way I tell my CSS that `bold=700` and not 400 (which is I reckon the default value) ?

=====

EDIT

I must have been unclear.

In CSS *only*, without modifying Bootstrap sources, there are many locations ([the whole list here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/search?q=bold&type=Code)) where bootstrap says (Eg.)

```
h6 {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

I'd like the web-browser to understand that in this case `bold` should be equivalent to `font-weight: 700` instead of `font-weight: 400` as per default without rewriting all the rules (Eg.)

```
h6 {
  font-weight: 700
}
```

The answer can be that it is not currently possible, but Google hasn't provided me any  answer yet.

Comment: Why not just do `font-weight: 700`? Or do you want to use `bold` as a shortcut (alias) for `700`? In the latter case, if you're using LESS this is pretty easy; you can just do `@bold-weight: 700` and then `tag { font-weight: @bold-weight; }`

Comment: That's pretty much what I want to do, but - if possible - in CSS instead of LESS (since I'd like to keep Bootstrap source unchanged).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make font-weight: bold equal to 500 instead of 700?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836290/is-it-possible-to-make-font-weight-bold-equal-to-500-instead-of-700)

Answer (score 5):

if you are using the `strong` tag.

```
strong {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

or if you are making elements bold using `font-weight:bold`, why not

```
elem {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Note: As @Pavlo pointed out, bold is equivalent to 700.

Comment: Actually `bold` is equivalent to `700`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#Values

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Open Sans, i would guess you are using `@fontface` - It's not advisable to set font-weight's using the font-weight property while using `@fontface` unless from something like Typekit. If your hosting your own fonts, i think adding font-weight will try and add a weight on a font that only has one weight.

Open sans i often use and i know comes in several weights all of which you reference in your style separately and call depending on what you need. So you would simply reference the `opensans-bold` or whichever weight you wanted.

However using fonts from google etc, i think font weights do work.

A good article [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/14/setting-weights-and-styles-at-font-face-declaration/)

Comment: +1, only answer to the point. Why not @font-face? It seems to be anyway the only thing to try, by pointing to different versions of the typeface: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2436830/931156 and http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-use-font-face-avoid-faux-italic-and-bold-browser-styles