# Is it possible to make font-weight: bold equal to 500 instead of 700?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I've just been playing with Google Fonts and found the Fira Sans font. It's nice but I don't like the Bold (700) style, it's too bold for my liking. However, if I select the Medium (500) style the browser doesn't use it for anything set to `font-weight: bold` (e.g. `<strong>`). Instead it uses some kind of faux bold that looks blurry.

I can go through my stylesheet and set every occurrence of `bold` to `500`. I could also use Sass to set a variable like `$bold-weight: 500;` which helps if I decide to change the font later.

That's a bit of a pain though, plus `bold` is also the default for many browser styles (e.g. `<strong>`, `<th>`) so I have to make sure I catch every possible occurrence of that too. And there may be external scripts/styles I don't control.

Is there a way to make all occurrences of `bold` use weight 500?

Comment: If I've understood MDN correctly, `bold` is basically an alias for 700. With that in mind, you are effectively asking if you can make 700 equal 500 which doesn't seem likely. I can understand why you are asking, but I think you are better off using a sass variable since it makes your intention clear

Comment: As a last resort, could you modify the font?

Comment: @Frits why did you delete your answer? It wasn't perfect but it wasn't a bad answer at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is,

When you choose to quick use a google font, you are provided with a link to include into the header, Open the link into your web browser and you would be served with a css file with lots of

```
/* cyrillic-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto Italic'), local('Roboto-Italic'),   url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/WxrXJa0C3KdtC7lMafG4dRTbgVql8nDJpwnrE27mub0.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
```

As you can see the `font-style: italic`  and the `font-weight: 400` is linked with some specific font (Roboto Italic here) within the `@font-face` tag, meaning whenever you use `font-weight: italic` with `font-weight: 400` (or `normal`), it refers to the font described within the src attribute.

Now, if you want to make all the `font-weight: bold` in your css use this font face, just change the `400` in above font-style to `bold` and you are done.

Or you can make a duplicate of the complete @font-face{..} and use another font-style into it.

Also, you can use *different fonts* here as well.  Make sure to keep only one font-style or font-weight tag within a @font-face.

This example here uses google fonts, you can use the same technique for self-hosted fonts.