# CSS font-weight not working on serbian latin letters

Tags: css, google-webfonts, latin

My problem is that `font-weight` in css doesn't apply on serbian latin characters (šđčćž ŠĐČĆŽ) which the font supports. for example:

```
#header h1{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 3px black;}
```

shows all letters bolded except serbian latin characters ON SOME COMPUTERS. It works on mine (win8), but not on two of theirs (win8.1 and winXP). Same HTML, same CSS, all three of us using Chrome and connected to the Internet. Do you have any idea what could it be?

Comment: look in the /windows/fonts/ directory and compare font files, I think you will find they are not the same, IE you have bold and they don't. Use a downloadable font for non-standard fonts ... http://www.google.com/fonts/

Comment: thanks wayne. the problem is that none of us has those fonts installed, they are imported directly from google. the text on their computers is also in that font, so are serbian letters, but only they are not bold.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this? [How to add multiple font files for the same font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-define-bold-italic-using-font-face) none of the SVG fonts that I have seen have different font-weights and I've not yet run into directions for creating additional font weights in that font file type. Some font files appear to have font weights, so my guess is that the systems are choosing or ending up with a different font file type.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying, but I've found the answer. I didn't import them properly from google website. for example, instead of:
`<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
I should have put
`<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif&subset=latin-ext,latin" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
Thanks!