# ExecCommand not unbolding

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, execcommand

Using a `selection / key command` based *WYSIWYG* editor. Works great EXCEPT...

With all the other key commands, it toggles the specific style I, strike, etc on and off.

With the `execCommand('bold')`, it doesn't unbold the text. It's very frustrating. It's the same for every browser.

Here's the code.

```
$('body').on('keydown', '.element_content, .element_content_subhead', function(e) { 

if(e.ctrlKey){

        //bold -- key 'B'
        if(e.which == 66){
            $sel = $.trim(document.getSelection().toString());
            if($sel == ''){
                alert('Please select some text to bold');
            }
            else{
                document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
            }
        }
       }

});
```

Comment: Let me add a few things...the using contentEditable <div> tags, and for the bold, actually using a stronger typeface in the CSS and not allowing the browser to bold the tag using fong-weight.

Comment: Nevermind. It was the font-weight:normal !important in the CSS that cause the unbolding error to trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer.

Because I was using a non-standard font (ClanWeb), the b to bold the type was not working well for the browsers. So in my CSS I had b{ font-family:ClanWeb-bold; font-weight:normal !important; }

This worked fine for bolding the type, but the execCommand wouldn't fire if the  tag didn't behave as normal; didn't have the font-weight:bold in the CSS.

So here was my code to unbold it.

```
  //bold -- key 'B'
    if(e.which == 66){
        $sel = $.trim(document.getSelection().toString());

        var parentEle = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
        parentEle = parentEle.parentNode;


        if($sel == ''){
            alert('Please select some text to bold');
        }
        else if(parentEle.tagName == 'B'){
            parentEle.id='unbold1'; 
            $('#unbold1').contents().unwrap();
        }
        else{
            document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can actually use the @font-face property to set the bold version of ClanWeb to be ClanWeb-bold. Then you won't need to set font-weight to normal! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-add-multiple-font-files-for-the-same-font

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in 'font: inherit;' bootstrap styles.
Summary: if you have problems with 'unbold' or 'unitalic' using **document.execComand** try to delete all css styles and check your editor - it should work fine after that.