# Using CSS @font-face properly

Tags: css, fonts

Hi I have a quick question on use CSS @font-face to create a font family.

Traditionally, I used to setup my CSS fonts like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font Regular';
    src: url('fonts/myfont.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font Bold';
    src: url('fonts/myfont-bold.ttf');
}
p { font-family: "My Font Regular";}
strong {font-family: "My Font Bold";}
```

However I've recently discovered that you can do it like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font';
    src: url('fonts/myfont.ttf');
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font';
    src: url('fonts/myfont-bold.ttf');
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:bold;
}
p { 
font-family: "My Font" ; 
font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
}
strong { 
font-family: "My Font" ;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:bold; 
}
```

My question is, if I use the second technique in bold for example, will the text still render using the custom .eot or will the browser try to emulate it without the using the actual bold font file?

Thanks

Comment: See [How to define bold, italic using @font-face](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-define-bold-italic-using-font-face).As a side note, be aware that [the EOT format is not supported by any browser other than IE](http://caniuse.com/eot).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I use:

```
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Franklin Demi';
            src: url('FranklinDemi.eot'),
                 url('FranklinDemi.ttf') format('truetype'),
                 url('FranklinDemi.svg#font') format('svg');
            }
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Franklin Heavy';
            src: url('FranklinHeavy.eot'),
                 url('FranklinHeavy.ttf') format('truetype'), 
                 url('FranklinHeavy.svg#font') format('svg');
            }
        .sidansTitel{
            font-family: 'Franklin Demi';
            font-size: 22pt;
            color: #8b9ba7;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
            }
        .sidansTitel b{
            font-family: 'Franklin Heavy';
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            }
```

Setting both `font-weight: normal;` and `font-style: normal;` makes the font render well in ie/ff/chrome, without it it looked like crap in Chrome. I believe that it looked like crap in Chrome because it tried to render the bold font in bold, which should be fixed by this.

EDIT: spelling

Answer (score 1):

If your font file is a bolded font, it would be redundant to set `font-weight: bold` and there's no need to declare `font-weight: normal` since that is the default value. You should also use more than `.eot` files so you have a fallback for other browsers like the others suggested.