# How to add fonts to create-react-app based projects?

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and prefer not to `eject`.

It's not clear where fonts imported via @font-face and loaded locally should go.

Namely, I'm loading

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Myriad Pro Regular'), url('MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Any suggestions?

-- EDIT

Including the gist to which Dan referring in his answer

```
➜  Client git:(feature/trivia-game-ui-2) ✗ ls -l public/static/fonts
total 1168
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 maximveksler  staff  62676 Mar 17  2014 MYRIADPRO-BOLD.woff
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 maximveksler  staff  61500 Mar 17  2014 MYRIADPRO-BOLDCOND.woff
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 maximveksler  staff  66024 Mar 17  2014 MYRIADPRO-BOLDCONDIT.woff
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 maximveksler  staff  66108 Mar 17  2014 MYRIADPRO-BOLDIT.woff
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 maximveksler  staff  60044 Mar 17  2014 MYRIADPRO-COND.woff
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 maximveksler  staff  64656 Mar 17  2014 MYRIADPRO-CONDIT.woff
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 maximveksler  staff  61848 Mar 17  2014 MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 maximveksler  staff  62448 Mar 17  2014 MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLD.woff
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 maximveksler  staff  66232 Mar 17  2014 MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLDIT.woff
➜  Client git:(feature/trivia-game-ui-2) ✗ cat src/containers/GameModule.css
.GameModule {
  padding: 15px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Myriad Pro Regular'), url('%PUBLIC_URL%/static/fonts/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Myriad Pro Condensed'), url('%PUBLIC_URL%/static/fonts/MYRIADPRO-COND.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Semibold Italic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Myriad Pro Semibold Italic'), url('%PUBLIC_URL%/static/fonts/MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLDIT.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Semibold';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Myriad Pro Semibold'), url('%PUBLIC_URL%/static/fonts/MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLD.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Condensed Italic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Myriad Pro Condensed Italic'), url('%PUBLIC_URL%/static/fonts/MYRIADPRO-CONDIT.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Bold Italic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Myriad Pro Bold Italic'), url('%PUBLIC_URL%/static/fonts/MYRIADPRO-BOLDIT.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Bold Condensed Italic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Myriad Pro Bold Condensed Italic'), url('%PUBLIC_URL%/static/fonts/MYRIADPRO-BOLDCONDIT.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Bold Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Myriad Pro Bold Condensed'), url('%PUBLIC_URL%/static/fonts/MYRIADPRO-BOLDCOND.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Bold';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Myriad Pro Bold'), url('%PUBLIC_URL%/static/fonts/MYRIADPRO-BOLD.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Comment: Have you checked "Adding Fonts" section in its User Guide?

Comment: @DanAbramov i have, the recommendation is to import the font. But I feel it's not clear (at least not to me) about how it should be done in practice. In the mean time I've done this https://gist.github.com/maximveksler/5b4f80c5ded20237c3deebc82a31dcd5 and it seems to work (web pack alerts if it can't find a font file) yet I'm sure it's not the optimal solution and an example or having it documented here would help. ty for reaching out!

Comment: I answered. Your approach looks wrong to me: `%PUBLIC_URL%` can't work (and is unnecessary) in a CSS file. Also, as described in the guide, you should be using JS imports in almost all cases, not the public folder.

Comment: Is there any utility/package to scan specified folder for fonts and generate the script file with all font variations? It's tedious to write that all manually

Comment: I came here to actually be able to "import" fonts, as I'm using react-pdf and want to actually import the actual font file, not css. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 631, accepted):

There are two options:

#### Using Imports

This is the suggested option. It ensures your fonts go through the build pipeline, get hashes during compilation so that browser caching works correctly, and that you get compilation errors if the files are missing.

As [described in “Adding Images, Fonts, and Files”](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files), you need to have a CSS file imported from JS. For example, by default `src/index.js` imports `src/index.css`:

```
import './index.css';
```

A CSS file like this goes through the build pipeline, and can reference fonts and images. For example, if you put a font in `src/fonts/MyFont.woff`, your `index.css` might include this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: local('MyFont'), url(./fonts/MyFont.woff) format('woff');
  /* other formats include: 'woff2', 'truetype, 'opentype',
                            'embedded-opentype', and 'svg' */
}
```

Notice how we’re using a relative path starting with `./`. This is a special notation that helps the build pipeline (powered by Webpack) discover this file.

Normally this should be enough.

#### Using `public` Folder

If for some reason you prefer *not* to use the build pipeline, and instead do it the “classic way”, you can [use the `public` folder](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-the-public-folder) and put your fonts there.

The downside of this approach is that the files don’t get hashes when you compile for production so you’ll have to update their names every time you change them, or browsers will cache the old versions.

If you want to do it this way, put the fonts somewhere into the `public` folder, for example, into `public/fonts/MyFont.woff`. If you follow this approach, you should put CSS files into `public` folder as well and *not* import them from JS because mixing these approaches is going to be very confusing. So, if you still want to do it, you’d have a file like `public/index.css`. You would have to manually add `<link>` to this stylesheet from `public/index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/index.css">
```

And inside of it, you would use the regular CSS notation:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: local('MyFont'), url(fonts/MyFont.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Notice how I’m using `fonts/MyFont.woff` as the path. This is because `index.css` is in the `public` folder so it will be served from the public path (usually it’s the server root, but if you deploy to GitHub Pages and set your `homepage` field to `http://myuser.github.io/myproject`, it will be served from `/myproject`). However `fonts` are also in the `public` folder, so they will be served from `fonts` relatively (either `http://mywebsite.example/fonts` or `http://myuser.github.io/myproject/fonts`). Therefore we use the relative path.

Note that since we’re avoiding the build pipeline in this example, it doesn’t verify that the file actually exists. This is why I don’t recommend this approach. Another problem is that our `index.css` file doesn’t get minified and doesn’t get a hash. So it’s going to be slower for the end users, and you risk the browsers caching old versions of the file.

#### Which Way to Use?

Go with the first method (“Using Imports”). I only described the second one since that’s what you attempted to do (judging by your comment), but it has many problems and should only be the last resort when you’re working around some issue.

Comment: got it, no reason not to use import.

Comment: an example in the docs would be useful, i was also a little confused

Comment: I found that I actually had to use the url ./fonts/Myfont.woff and not ./Myfont.woff

Comment: If someone is adding a ```ttf``` font, you should give ```truetype``` instead of ```ttf``` as the parameter to the ```format```[*](https://scotch.io/@micwanyoike/how-to-add-fonts-to-a-react-project).

Comment: I can confirm what @th3morg said.

Comment: Following @milkersarac if you are using `otf` you need to put `opentype`.

Comment: The fonts are getting loaded but the files has the '<hash>.ttf' and they are not getting loading because the index.css file still has the regular route. Any ideas?

Comment: "This is a special notation that helps the build pipeline (powered by Webpack) discover this file", would be nice with an inclusion of what type of webpack extension and setup is required to this preferred way.

Comment: @milkersarac 's comment should be added to answer - this SAVED me

Comment: More than one style for one family (`bold`, `bold+italic`, ..)? This one should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2436830/3592419

Comment: what about styled components?

Comment: Is there a way to do this using imports without putting font files into src folder?

Comment: Solution 1 worked great with react-native-web, use fontWeight e.g. fontWeight: 100 etc to make font thinner or bolder.

Comment: Hey @DanAbramove, I was using the first method you described here, but when I analyse the site wit lighthouse, it suggested to preload the font file, how can we do preloading with 1st approach? I tried different things, no luck just yet

Answer (score 181):

Here are some ways of doing this:

### 1. Importing font

For example, for using Roboto, install the package using

```
yarn add typeface-roboto
```

or

```
npm install typeface-roboto --save
```

In index.js:

```
import "typeface-roboto";
```

There are npm packages for a lot of open source fonts and most of Google fonts. You can see all fonts [here](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typefaces/tree/master/packages). All the packages are from that [project](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typefaces/).

### 2. For fonts hosted by Third party

For example Google fonts, you can go to [fonts.google.com](http://fonts.google.com) where you can find links that you can put in your `public/index.html`

[image: screenshot of fonts.google.com]

It'll be like

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
</style>
```

### 3. Downloading the font and adding it in your source code.

Download the font. For example, for google fonts, you can go to [fonts.google.com](http://fonts.google.com). Click on the download button to download the font.

Move the font to `fonts` directory in your `src` directory

```
src
|
`----fonts
|      |
|      `-Lato/Lato-Black.ttf
|       -Lato/Lato-BlackItalic.ttf
|       -Lato/Lato-Bold.ttf
|       -Lato/Lato-BoldItalic.ttf
|       -Lato/Lato-Italic.ttf
|       -Lato/Lato-Light.ttf
|       -Lato/Lato-LightItalic.ttf
|       -Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf
|       -Lato/Lato-Thin.ttf
|       -Lato/Lato-ThinItalic.ttf
|
`----App.css
```

Now, in `App.css`, add this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  src: local('Lato'), url(./fonts/Lato-Regular.otf) format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 900;
    src: local('Lato'), url(./fonts/Lato-Bold.otf) format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 900;
    src: local('Lato'), url(./fonts/Lato-Black.otf) format('opentype');
}
```

For `ttf` format, you have to mention `format('truetype')`. For `woff`, `format('woff')`

Now you can use the font in classes.

```
.modal-title {
    font-family: Lato, Arial, serif;
    font-weight: black;
}
```

### 4. Using web-font-loader package

Install package using

```
yarn add webfontloader
```

or

```
npm install webfontloader --save
```

In `src/index.js`, you can import this and specify the fonts needed

```
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';

WebFont.load({
   google: {
     families: ['Titillium Web:300,400,700', 'sans-serif']
   }
});
```

Comment: @sudobangbang Thanks, solution #3 worked for me. However - is there a way not to put `fonts` folder under `src`, but under `public` instead? I tried it, but it seems not allowed...

Comment: @YossiVainshtein, I don't think so. As you're using the fonts in App.css, it should also be compiled with it.

Comment: `For ttf format, you have to mention format('truetype'). For woff, format('woff')` did it for me! thank you!

Comment: Web fonts loaded from source is the way to go. If you try loading them from Google you'll get dinged in by Lighthouse and you'll lose page speed (not to mention users in China). To improve the performance of your web fonts install `woff2` cli tool and use its `woff2_compress` binary on Google Font TTF download files to compress them for Web. In your `@font-face` rules use the [`font-display` rule](https://caniuse.com/#search=font-display) to speed things up even more. Finally, you _only_ need to ship WOFF2 files for Web.

Comment: Typeface is deprecated, use fontsource: https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful. Please update font-family: 'Lato'; to different name to use different type of font. Like LatoRegular, LatoBold and so on.

Answer (score 11):

1. Go to Google Fonts https://fonts.google.com/
2. Select your font as depicted in image below:

[image]

3. Copy and then paste that url in new tab you will get the css code to add that font. In this case if you go to

> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spicy+Rice

It will open like this:

[image]

4, Copy and paste that code in your style.css and simply start using that font like this:

```
      <Typography
          variant="h1"
          gutterBottom
          style={{ fontFamily: "Spicy Rice", color: "pink" }}
        >
          React Rock
        </Typography>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: In many cases (ex: corporate networks), access to external CDN is blocked by firewall and this method, although correct, may not work. We have multiple VLANs in our organization and except IT and few others all VLANs block external CDN access which also means Google's content CDN are also blocked. Been there, done that.

Answer (score 7):

When using different font files for normal/italic `font-style` the way you specify `@font-face` might need to be different depending on entry point. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731492/font-face-does-not-work-properly-for-italic-bold-fonts/67684681#answer-67684681):

1. If you choose to link the `css` file directly to your `public/index.html` then you can use `font-face` normally with one `font-family` name and different `font-style`:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontName"; <---
  font-style: normal; <---
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("path-to-assets/fonts/FontName.ttf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontName"; <---
  font-style: italic; <---
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("path-to-assets/fonts/FontName-Italic.ttf") format("truetype");
}

/* Usage */
.text {
  font-family: FontName;
  font-style: normal;
}
.text-italic {
  font-family: FontName;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

2. If you choose to link the `css` file via Js for bundling, then you need to have a different `font-family` name for all your `italic` fonts and use `font-style` normal.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontName"; <---
  font-style: normal; <---
  font-weight: normal; /* normal | 300 | 400 | 600 | bold | etc */
  src: url("path-to-assets/fonts/FontName.ttf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontNameItalic";
  font-style: normal; <----
  font-weight: normal; /* normal | 300 | 400 | 600 | bold | etc */
  src: url("path-to-assets/fonts/FontName-Italic.ttf") format("truetype");
}

/* Usage */
.text {
  font-family: FontName;
}
.text-italic {
  font-family: FontNameItalic;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Local fonts linking to your react js may be a failure. So, I prefer to use online css file from google to link fonts. Refer the following code,

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Web API FontFace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/FontFace) constructor (also Typescript) without need of CSS:

```js
export async function loadFont(fontFamily: string, url: string): Promise<void> {
    const font = new FontFace(fontFamily, `local(${fontFamily}), url(${url})`);
    // wait for font to be loaded
    await font.load();
    // add font to document
    document.fonts.add(font);
    // enable font with CSS class
    document.body.classList.add("fonts-loaded");
}
```

```js
import ComicSans from "./assets/fonts/ComicSans.ttf";

loadFont("Comic Sans ", ComicSans).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

[Declare a file `font.ts`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101503/5164462) with your modules (TS only):

```
declare module "*.ttf";
declare module "*.woff";
declare module "*.woff2";
```

If TS cannot find FontFace type as its still officially WIP, add [this declaration](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30984#issuecomment-631991019) to your project. It will work in your browser, except for IE.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [WebFont](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfont) module, which greatly simplifies the process.

```
render(){
  webfont.load({
     custom: {
       families: ['MyFont'],
       urls: ['/fonts/MyFont.woff']
     }
  });
  return (
    <div style={your style} >
      your text!
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was making mistakes like this.

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext";
@import "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css";
```

It works properly this way

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext);
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css);
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent the entire morning solving a similar problem after having landed on this stack question. I used Dan's first solution in the answer above as the jump off point.

**Problem**

I have a dev (this is on my local machine), staging, and production environment. My staging and production environments live on the same server.

The app is deployed to staging via `acmeserver/~staging/note-taking-app` and the production version lives at `acmeserver/note-taking-app` (blame IT).

All the media files such as fonts were loading perfectly fine on dev (i.e., `react-scripts start`).

However, when I created and uploaded staging and production builds, while the `.css` and `.js` files were loading properly, fonts were not. The compiled `.css` file looked to have a correct path but the browser http request was getting some very wrong pathing (shown below).

The compiled `main.fc70b10f.chunk.css` file:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: SairaStencilOne-Regular;
  src: url(note-taking-app/static/media/SairaStencilOne-Regular.ca2c4b9f.ttf) ("truetype");
}
```

The browser http request is shown below. Note how it is adding in `/static/css/` when the font file just lives in `/static/media/` as well as duplicating the destination folder. I ruled out the server config being the culprit.

The `Referer` is partly at fault too.

```
GET /~staging/note-taking-app/static/css/note-taking-app/static/media/SairaStencilOne-Regular.ca2c4b9f.ttf HTTP/1.1
Host: acmeserver
Origin: http://acmeserver
Referer: http://acmeserver/~staging/note-taking-app/static/css/main.fc70b10f.chunk.css
```

The `package.json` file had the `homepage` property set to `./note-taking-app`. This was causing the problem.

```
{
  "name": "note-taking-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./note-taking-app",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -e development react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -e staging npm run build",
    "build:production": "env-cmd -e production npm run build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
  //...
}
```

**Solution**

That was long winded — but the solution is to:

1. change the `PUBLIC_URL` env variable depending on the environment
2. remove the `homepage` property from the `package.json` file

Below is my `.env-cmdrc` file. I use `.env-cmdrc` over regular `.env` because it keeps everything together in one file.

```
{
  "development": {
    "PUBLIC_URL": "",
    "REACT_APP_API": "http://acmeserver/~staging/note-taking-app/api"
  },
  "staging": {
    "PUBLIC_URL": "/~staging/note-taking-app",
    "REACT_APP_API": "http://acmeserver/~staging/note-taking-app/api"
  },
  "production": {
    "PUBLIC_URL": "/note-taking-app",
    "REACT_APP_API": "http://acmeserver/note-taking-app/api"
  }
}
```

Routing via `react-router-dom` works fine too — simply use the `PUBLIC_URL` env variable as the `basename` property.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const createRouter = RootComponent => (
  <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <RootComponent />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export { createRouter };
```

The server config is set to route all requests to the `./index.html` file.

Finally, here is what the compiled `main.fc70b10f.chunk.css` file looks like after the discussed changes were implemented.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: SairaStencilOne-Regular;
  src: url(/~staging/note-taking-app/static/media/SairaStencilOne-Regular.ca2c4b9f.ttf)
    format("truetype");
}
```

**Reading material**

- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env
- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing
- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration

  - this explains the `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable

    > Create React App assumes your application is hosted at the serving web server's root or a subpath as specified in package.json (homepage). Normally, Create React App ignores the hostname. You may use this variable to force assets to be referenced verbatim to the url you provide (hostname included). This may be particularly useful when using a CDN to host your application.

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Sanchez-Regular';
    src: local('Sanchez-Regular'),url(../assets/fonts/Sanchez/Sanchez-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

and it worked awesomely
just later use it like we use all other fonts after doing this in index.css

Answer (score 0):

This is for people using an NX(nwrl) monorepo, I have tested this while using it there, may work for other CRA apps.
First add the fonts in the assets/fonts folder, create a fonts folder, if not present.

Then in your main app.js/tsx
Add this code, with your existing jsx code

```
<style type="text/css">{`
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'MaterialIcons';
      src: url(${require('react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf')}) format('truetype');
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'MaterialCommunityIcons';
      src: url(${require('react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf')}) format('truetype');
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Mulish-Bold';
      src: url(${require('../assets/fonts/Mulish-Bold.ttf')}) format('truetype');
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Your Font Name';
      src: url(${require('../assets/fonts/font-file-name.otf')}) format('truetype');
    }
  `}</style>
```

It should look something like this, wrap with Fragment tags -

```
 <>
<style type="text/css">{`
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'MaterialIcons';
          src: url(${require('react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf')}) format('truetype');
        }
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'MaterialCommunityIcons';
          src: url(${require('react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf')}) format('truetype');
        }
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Mulish-Bold';
          src: url(${require('../assets/fonts/Mulish-Bold.ttf')}) format('truetype');
        }
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'CircularStd-Book';
          src: url(${require('../assets/fonts/CircularStd-Book.otf')}) format('truetype');
        }
      `}</style>
   //Your JSX, or your main app level code
 </>
```

There's another step, in your custom webpack config file, add these loaders, if you don't have one then, on your parent level, create a webpack.js file -

Your webpack js should look something like this -

```
const getWebpackConfig = require('@nrwl/react/plugins/webpack');

function getCustomWebpackConfig(webpackConfig) {
  const config = getWebpackConfig(webpackConfig);
  const isProduction = webpackConfig.mode === 'production';

  if (!isProduction) {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
      'react-native-linear-gradient': 'react-native-web-linear-gradient',
      'react-native-localization': 'react-localization'
    };

    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
        options: { esModule: false, name: 'static/media/[path][name].[ext]' },
      },
      {
        test: /\.otf$/,
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
        options: { esModule: false, name: 'static/media/[path][name].[ext]' },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: function (content) {
          return (
            /node_modules/.test(content) &&
            !/\/react-native-paper\//.test(content) &&
            !/\/react-native-vector-icons\//.test(content) &&
          
          );
        },
        use: {
          loader: require.resolve('@nrwl/web/src/utils/web-babel-loader.js'),
          options: {
            presets: [
              [
                '@nrwl/react/babel',
                {
                  runtime: 'automatic',
                  useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                },
              ],
            ],
            plugins: [
                ["module-resolver", {
                    "alias": {
                      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
                      "react-native-linear-gradient": "react-native-web-linear-gradient",
                      "react-native-localization": "react-localization"
                    }
                  }]
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      
    );
  }

  return config;
}

module.exports = getCustomWebpackConfig;
```

Your babel loader, may be different but the ttf and otf rules are important to be added. I'm using this with react native for web functionality. You could remove the aliases if it isn't required by your project.

Thanks to this blog, which made me understand this concept better - https://blog.nrwl.io/step-by-step-guide-on-creating-a-monorepo-for-react-native-apps-using-nx-704753b6c70e

Answer (score 0):

My feeling was that if you have the font hosted locally on your website, you should be able to use the [CSS Font Loading API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API) to do the font loading for you *at runtime* without using a CSS file. This is a React component I wrote to do this. It is based on [user-rebo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5164462/user-rebo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65919594/7120459) above, but tries to unload the font after usage. It seems to work in Firefox and Chrome. The code is:

```
import React, { useEffect, PropsWithChildren, useRef } from "react";

type FontFaceFormat =
  | "woff"
  | "woff2"
  | "truetype"
  | "opentype"
  | "embedded-opentype"
  | "svg";

type FontWrapperProps = {
  fontName: string;
  fontURL: string;
  fontFormat?: FontFaceFormat;
};

/*
 * The FontWrapper class. Takes a fontName (like "Andika"), a fontURL (which
 * should go to the website's public folder), and an optional font type. Usage
 * should be as simple as:
 *
 * <FontWrapper fontName="Andika" fontURL="/fonts/Andika-Regular.ttf.woff2">
 *   <p>This is some text</p>
 * </FontWrapper>
 *
 * Note: document.fonts is of type FontFaceSet, which should include the add() and
 * delete() methods. However, the TypeScript libraries for Visual Studio Code
 * miss these. That's why I have two instances of "document.fonts as any" -
 * to make those red lines go away.
 */

export default function FontWrapper({
  fontName,
  fontURL,
  fontFormat = "woff2",
  children,
}: PropsWithChildren<FontWrapperProps>) {
  const fontRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadFont = async () => {
      const font = new FontFace(
        fontName,
        `url(${fontURL}) format("${fontFormat}")`,
        {}
      );
      const fontResult = await font.load();
      fontRef.current = fontResult;
      await (document.fonts as any).add(font);
    };

    const unloadFont = async () => {
      await (document.fonts as any).delete(fontRef.current);
    };

    loadFont();

    return () => {
      unloadFont();
    };
  }, []);

  return <div style={{ fontFamily: fontName }}>{children}</div>;
}
```

Usage is:

```
<FontWrapper fontName="Andika" fontURL="/fonts/Andika-Regular.ttf.woff2">
  <p>This is some text</p>
</FontWrapper>
```