# Import font into React application

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, material-design

I'm trying to use the Roboto font in my app and having tough time..

I did `npm install --save typeface-roboto` and added `import 'typeface-roboto'` to my React component. But still can't get my font to change.

I am trying to do like this :

```
const React = require('react')
import 'typeface-roboto'

class Example extends React.Component {

  render() {

    let styles = {
      root: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto'
      }
    }

    return (
      <div style={styles.root}>
        <p>
          This text is still not Roboto ?!???!!1
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
module.exports = Example
```

Am I missing something? Looking for a simple way to do this without any external css file..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676054/how-to-add-fonts-to-create-react-app-based-projects

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin thanks but I came across that question before asking and it made no sense to me at all (im not using create-react-app)... Is there no way to use a font from a local file (node module) with react inline styling (no css file) ??

Comment: Could you check [this](https://scotch.io/@micwanyoike/how-to-add-fonts-to-a-react-project) article, it might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add fonts to create-react-app based projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676054/how-to-add-fonts-to-create-react-app-based-projects)

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `import 'typeface-roboto';` in root file i.e. index.js file.

In my case I added font-family to body element and it is worked.

Comment: Agreed. I put `import 'typeface-roboto';` in index.js, then I added `font-family: 'Roboto';` in my separate index.css file, and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

import this code of line in your main css or scss whatever use use

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap');
```

this will work. 
If you want to customize this then go to the google font and select font style font weight whatever you want. 
Here i have selected font weight 400,300 and 700 
If have not selected the font weight then you can not use other font weight

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, couldn't get Roboto fonts for my components anyhow.

I used the webfontloader package.

```
yarn add webfontloader
```

or

```
npm install webfontloader --save
```

h
Once you do this, add the following code to your **index.js** or to the JS file which is an **entry point to your application**

```
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';

WebFont.load({
  google: {
    families: ['Titillium Web:300,400,700', 'sans-serif']
  }
});
// rest of the index.js code
```

And now apply the font-family.

Answer (score 1):

You simply just require('typeface-roboto') it.

```js
const React = require('react')
require('typeface-roboto')

class Example extends React.Component {

  render() {

    let styles = {
      root: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto'
      }
    }

    return (
      <div style={styles.root}>
        <p>
          This is now Roboto
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```css
// or here instead if you fancy
    .root {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
```

Comment: require is depricted in es 6

Answer (score 1):

It involves several changes, assuming you want to use CSSinJS:

1. change `style` to `className`
2. You'll need some kind of library to apply `styles`.

**With react-jss**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'typeface-roboto';
import injectSheet from 'react-jss';

const styles = {
  root: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  },
};

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.root}>
        This text is Roboto
      </div>
    )

  }
}

const StyledExample = injectSheet(styles)(Example)

export default StyledExample;
```

**Or with MaterialUI styles:**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'typeface-roboto';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  },
});

function Example(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      This text is Roboto
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Example);
```

Or, [you could just do it the right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676054/how-to-add-fonts-to-create-react-app-based-projects), via Dan's Answer

Or the Styled-Components way:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const ExampleStyled = styled.div`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: local('Roboto'), url(fonts/Roboto.woff) format('woff');
  }
`

const Example = () => (
  <ExampleStyled>
     This text is Roboto!
  </ExampleStyled>
);

export default Example;
```