# Import local font to create-react-app project

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, create-react-app

I created a React app using `create-react-app` and chose to not eject. Currently, I'm trying to import a local font using `@font-face`, but I'm not succeeding.

This is my current folder structure:

```
/
+ public/
+ src/
-- index.js
-- App.js
-- App.css
++ assets/
+++ css/
---- general.css
+++ fonts/
---- CircularStd-Medium.woff
```

On the `App.js`, I'm importing `general.css` file (`import './assets/css/general.css';`).

On `general.css` file, I'm setting the `@font-face` as described below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CircularStd-Medium';
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('CircularStd-Medium'), local('CircularStd-Medium'),
    url('../fonts/CircularStd-Medium.woff') format('woff'), 
}
```

I already tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678350/2460341), but it did't work. The code compiles, but a simple Times New Roman shows up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

funnily enough, Im importing the same font. It wasn't working when I had it in the public folder. So I moved it to my "router" area (because it is also pretty global). The font now goes through the build pipeline and works

```
require('./fonts/circular-std-master/css/circular-std.css');
```

Check out my repo for the code ;)

https://github.com/maltenz/malte/tree/master/src/Router

Comment: Lol even I am importing the same font in 2019

Comment: That repo page is not available @Malte Schulze-Boeing

Answer (score 1):

I keep my local fonts in `/public/fonts` and in the stylesheet (I use sass) the url that picked the fonts is `/fonts/myfont`
Note the / at the beginning.

It is the same for images referenced in stylesheet (/img/myimage)