# How to add local / custom fonts to a react js project?

Tags: html, reactjs, sass

I want to add some custom / local fonts to my react project, can anyone tell me the method to use it inside react project ?

Below I have added some ss of my code which is not working.

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0dOY.png)

[index.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feBwC.png)

[app.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C9VX.png)

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676054/how-to-add-fonts-to-create-react-app-based-projects

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I have added ss of my code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You import the `bold` font in your `index.js` but you set the `book` font in your `App.scss`. Also try to add `!important` when setting the `font-family` on the body:

```
html,
body {
  font-family: "CooperHewitt-Bold" !important;
}
```

Using `@font-face`:

```
/* index.css */ 
@font-face {
  font-family: "CooperHewitt-Bold";
  src: local("CooperHewitt-Bold"),
    url(./fonts/CooperHewitt-Bold.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

Make sure to import `index.css` inside `index.js`:

```
import './index.css';
// ...
```