# I am unable to get the given font in my react app - only getting it for some text

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native

[I want to change all my font family in app to helvetica and this was i was doing but i am unable to change my font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EXSo.png)

Comment: Is this css being included in the build? Do you have Helvetica @font-face included? I would add a fallback as `monospace` to check that the correct font is being used.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this answer it explains the possible solution for you question https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678350/9741427

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).