# How to set font family in react js website globally?

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, material-ui

I have issue to set helvetica neue font family globally. It gives error as: **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin**.
Then I have used **crossorigin="anonymous"** with it but doesn't work and again gives error **GET https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/helvetica-neue-9 net::ERR_ABORTED 503**. How can I solve this issue?

In index.html I am using font inside Head tag as:

`<link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/helvetica-neue-9" rel="stylesheet" />`

In index.css file I am using as:

body {
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue",
Helvetica, "Lucida Grande";
}

Error in console:[image]

Comment: Are you using a custom setup fro your project?

Comment: No, I am not using custom setup.

Comment: This should provide you with the answer: [How to add fonts to create-react-app based projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676054/how-to-add-fonts-to-create-react-app-based-projects)