# execCommand() doesn't "unbold" text

Tags: javascript, html, css, execcommand

I made my own WYSIWYG text-editor.

The contenteditable-field is a div, see code below:

```
<div spellcheck="false" id="textEditorField" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

The button-events look like this:

```
boldButton.onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand('bold', false, null); 
    return false; 
}
```

The texteditor is working fine. It italics and un-italics the text, underlining works.
But with bold there is a problem: it bolds the text, but doesn't unbold it. This is in every browser on both OS X and Windows.

I'm using a custom font which is imported using `@font-face`.

In the css I do the following:

```
b {
    font-family: "Caviar Dreams Bold";
    font-weight: normal;
}
b i, i b {
    font-family: "Caviar Dreams Bold Italic";
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

If I remove the `font-weight` property the text gets the font-family "Caviar Dreams Bold" AND it is made bold via CSS, so extra bold.

There are some similar questions, but without an answer I can use. I also have to note that I can't use jQuery for this.

Comment: Looks like a JavaScript issue. Inspect your DOM and see if the <b></b> is really being removed. I've created a simple editor myself here https://github.com/NenadP/biu-editor if you need inspiration :)

Comment: It looks like it's removed and added again instantly. Because in web-inspector it has `<b></b>`. If I expand this tag and then try to unbold the text the tags collapse again.

Comment: It's not a general issue, it's something specific in your code. Provide some jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: Finally I got the JSFiddle working, and luckily the problem exists here too (else it would be even more difficult to solve I guess). Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/ume3t0vp/

Comment: OK, I understood what is the problem. Will post my answer in some minutes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `execCommand('bold'...` works as expected, i.e. toggles the surrounding of the text in  tag. The problem is that you set `'font-weight: normal'` style for the b tag in the following CSS classes. It means that you explicitly want the text in the `<b>` tag to be normal and it's what you get.

```
b {
    font-family: "Caviar Dreams Bold";
    font-weight: normal;
}
b i, i b {
    font-family: "Caviar Dreams Bold Italic";
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

So, you should remove this property and everything work fine.

UPDATE:

It's important to understand how in certain circumstances the method may "bold but not unbold". In fact, `execCommand` makes something more smart than just surrounding the text. It also normalizes it taking in account that there may be a mix of crossing tags like `<b>` or `<strong>` together with `<i>`, `<u>`, etc. The browser algorithm analyses the text styles to understand what is actually bold and why. When you redefine bold to normal it may cause the algorithm to decide: "OK, although it's inside `<b>` tag, the text is not bold and so there is nothing to change" and keeps the tag.

Comment: I didn't expect the `execCommand()`-algorithm to be _this_ smart. You are right, this is the solution. But the thing now is: the text in the contenteditable `div` that's being set to bold is _extra_ bold, because of the font (Caviar Dreams BOLD) + the font-weight. I guess the best/only solution is to give the `b`-element for this div the font "Caviar Dreams REGULAR" so it looks bold?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the most correct solution. BTW, why have you decided to use this font? Being really nice for a large size typography, in WYSIWYG editor it look not different from something simple and standard like arial...

Comment: Thank you. I will use this. About the font? I don't know. I'm studying software engineering, so I'm absolutely NOT a designer. ;) I will maybe look into some other fonts (and color schemes) for the website I'm building for the course Client.

Comment: If you want to use a fancy bolded font, rather than setting the family and then font-weight to normal (and breaking execCommand), you can instead extend the original font-family with @font-face to tell the browser which font to use when font-weight is set to "bold". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-add-multiple-font-files-for-the-same-font

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#textEditorField * {
    font-family: unset;
}
#textEditorField b {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```