# Internet Explorer execCommand bold not resetting

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have an issue on a big app that I cannot reproduce on a basic test page :

In a contentEditable div I have an onclick function that triggers

```
document.execCommand("bold", false, "");
```

On a basic test page, when I hit it the first time it adds `<strong>text</strong>` tags.
But when I hit it a second time, i expect it to clear the strong tags and go back to "text"

On the big app, I end up addindg more and more tags, like `<strong><strong><strong>text</strong></strong></strong>`

Any idea of what is making that ?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: It seems you work with jscript, not javascript.

Comment: I also created a simple example to test it, and as you mentioned, it works correctly in a simple test page. I'm not sure what environment you are describing for the big application. Is it possible that it is affected by the font style? Refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614760/execcommand-doesnt-unbold-text).

Comment: thanks Xudong Peng I'll have a look if css is messing things up or not