# How to use font-family with same name?

Tags: css

Here is the css: one is Regular and other one is Bold but both has same font-family name.

How to differentiate and use it in our stylesheet?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Why are you keeping same font name? :/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-add-multiple-font-files-for-the-same-font - PS @Mr_Green That is legal as long as the `@font-face` contains -style and -weight directives.

Comment: @wiesion, exactly. That is what I have been trying to say.

Comment: @wiesion that is strange.. I will learn something new today if it is true. I am doing research.

Comment: sometimes when we generate the CSS for newly installed fonts we get the same font-family names,but with different font-weight and font-style.In that case we can use same font-family with different font-weight or style,whichever required!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use different weights.

Give the first one a weight of `200` and the second one a weight of `300`. Then, you can use the two:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 200 /* for the first one */ 
/* or font-weight: 300; for the second one */
```

> EDIT: After the OP specified the weights

You can give the following attributes to the second (bold) one:

```
font-weight: bold;
font-weight: 700; /* fallback */
```

and the following to the first (regular) one:

```
font-weight: 300;
```

Now, to use the bold one:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: bold; /* or 700 */
```

and to use the normal one, switch the `font-weight`:

```
font-weight: 300;
```

There you go! :)

Mr_Green, fresh out of Google's Font CSS:

[image: have a look]

> A basic analogy to describe how the `font-weight` rule works

When you describe a font with a name, imagine (in the most abstract of the explanations) that you create an object; but, when you create multiple font-rules with the same name, imagine you create an array. Now, to access and array, you have to use its `index`. The `index` here is the `font-weight`. So, to access different weights (technically, fonts), you use the weight. Continuing the analogy of the array above, you **have to manually**
define the index, it's not automatically done.

I think this makes it a little more clear.

Comment: by just using the same font-family name and with different font-weight property? yea..? like this.. {font-family:'Montserrat'; font-weight:normal;} for regular..and {font-family:'Montserrat'; font-weight:bold;} for bold?

Comment: @weirdpanda that is weird. are you sure? (_to me it seems you are trolling with OP_)

Comment: @Mr_Green, indeed. That's the way you use a font with multiple weights. People prefer to use `FONTNAMEBold`, but that's bad for maintainability; the preferred (and documented) way is to use `font-weights`.

Comment: So @weirdpanda, just a question.... How do I choose to call either font family in my CSS, since the syntax for both would be `font-family:'Montserrat';`

Comment: That's very simple; use the `font-weight`. I have given the definition of the style. For the bold one, you use `font-weight: bold;` and for the normal `font-weight: 300;`. Simple! :)

Comment: @masmrdrr, have a look at the analogy I have drawn to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

The `font-family` value does not have to be unique: [According to the w3 consortium](https://www.w3.org/TR/2019/WD-css-fonts-4-20191113/#font-family-prop), 'a font family defines a set of faces that vary in weight, width or slope. CSS uses the combination of a family name [i.e. `font-family`] with other font properties [`src`, `font-style`, `font-weight` and `font-stretch`] to select an individual face'. That is, two different `@font-face` rules may have the same `font-family` value (e.g. 'Montserrat') but be distinguished by e.g. different `font-weight` values (e.g. bold and normal, resp.). In this way different fonts can be selected.

The CSS style specified by @nag looks ok to me.
How to distinguish them? With selector-specific CSS. Mostly set by the developers.
However, since usually user agents define [default CSS styles](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) for standard html elements, most of the time you don't need to (set CSS for these). E.g. assuming you have somewhere defined the `font-family` as being Montserrat (e.g. in the `body`), and default CSS styles are not overridden, the content of the `strong` element, as in

```
<strong>I'm bold</strong>
```

is 'automatically' rendered bold because its default CSS style is usually:

```
strong {
  font-weight: bold; /* this is the same as 700 b.t.w.*/
}
```

So, the font in the `@font-face` rule with `font-weight: bold` will automatically be selected.

Also good to know: Again [according to the w3 consortium](https://www.w3.org/TR/2019/WD-css-fonts-4-20191113/#font-synthesis-intro), if a requested font style is not found, the user agent can synthesize the requested style from the nearest similar one. But this is 'only' the case for `italics` and `bold` as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use different font-family names for both Bold and Regular fonts, then refer in CSS as usual like below.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'MontserratBold';
   src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Bold.eot');
   src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('fonts/Montserrat-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
   url('fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
   src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.eot');
   src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
   url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```