# React JS - Using different fonts for different font weights?

Tags: css, reactjs, import, fonts

I'm trying to use different fonts for different font weights in ReactJS, but having tried two different import methods in our global stylesheet, I can only load either the first or last imported font.

Is this possible in ReactJS? I've never had a problem using the same sort of method elsewhere.

This only loads the first font:

```
css.global(
'@font-face', {
  fontFamily: 'ModernEra',
  src: `url( ${ModernEraLight} )`,
  fontWeight: 'lighter',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
},
'@font-face', {
  fontFamily: 'ModernEra',
  src: `url( ${ModernEraRegular} )`,
  fontWeight: 'normal',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
},
'@font-face', {
  fontFamily: 'ModernEra',
  src: `url( ${ModernEraMedium} )`,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
},
'@font-face', {
  fontFamily: 'ModernEra',
  src: `url( ${ModernEraBold} )`,
  fontWeight: 'bolder',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
}
);
css.global('html', {
  color: '#231e21',
  fontFamily: 'ModernEra, sans-serif',
  userSelect: 'none',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
});
```

And this only loads the last (I can see why):

```
css.global('@font-face', {
  fontFamily: 'ModernEra',
  src: `url( ${ModernEraLight} )`,
  fontWeight: 'lighter',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
});
css.global('@font-face', {
  fontFamily: 'ModernEra',
  src: `url( ${ModernEraRegular} )`,
  fontWeight: 'normal',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
});
css.global('@font-face', {
  fontFamily: 'ModernEra',
  src: `url( ${ModernEraMedium} )`,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
});
css.global('@font-face', {
  fontFamily: 'ModernEra',
  src: `url( ${ModernEraBold} )`,
  fontWeight: 'bolder',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
});
css.global('html', {
  color: '#231e21',
  fontFamily: 'ModernEra, sans-serif',
  userSelect: 'none',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
});
```

I'd like to be able to define the font with either 'lighter', 'normal', 'bold' or 'bolder'. Has anyone come up against the same issue, or have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple font-weights, one @font-face query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279989/multiple-font-weights-one-font-face-query)

Comment: @MTCoster - sadly not; I read that question, but it doesn't resolve the issue I'm having.

Comment: Is this vanilla React or are you using another library (like [glamor](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor)) to expose the `css` object?

Comment: @MTCoster I'm using glamor.

Comment: There’s a [very old open issue](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor/issues/40) over in the glamor repo regarding something similar. Note there have been no updates to glamor for over a year - I wouldn’t hold out hope for a fix anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks, @MTCoster. I know that glamorous is no longer supported - they're suggesting everyone moves over to emotion, but I was hoping for a quick fix before I have to migrate all our code.

Comment: Here's a solution that might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/33687499/4525600

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the font weight specified aren't enumerating to their rightful numeric values. Therefore, try specifying numeric values as well!

Here's a posted solution that helped me understand and resolve this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33687499/4525600

[image: Credit to weirdpanda]

*Credit to weirdpanda*

Hope this is helpful