# Add font weight to custom added font in react-native

Tags: react-native, fonts

I added 2 fonts in `React Native` app. The one is: `MyFont-Regular` and the other is `MyFont-Bold`. I can use them with `fontFamily: 'MyFont-Regular'` and `fontFamily: 'MyFont-Bold'`. However, I would like to use the `Regular` font as `fontFamily: 'MyFont'` and the `bold` as `style: {fontFamily: 'MyFont', fontWeight: 'bold'`. Is there some workaround?

I added the fonts as assets using

`"rnpm": {
    "assets": ["some_path/fonts"]
  }`

in my `package.json` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**STEP 1:** Assuming you have an **./assets/fonts/** folder, just name your font file **MyFont**.

**STEP 2:** Then, add this code to your **./package.json**:

```
“rnpm”: {
   “assets”: [“./assets/fonts”]
}
```

**STEP 3:** Run in terminal:

> $ react-native link

You should then see something like this:

[image]

If you want to make it bold, you can style it such as:
**fontWeight: 'bold'** OR **fontWeight: 700**

**UPDATE:** Knowing that the font we're talking about is Pensum Pro, it is not possible to use the same font file for multiple font weights.

*edit#1: typo*

*edit#2: added info*

Comment: If it doesn't work out for you, comment and I'll try to help.

Comment: I tried fontFamily: 'MyFont-Regular', fontWeight: 'bold', but it didn't work out. Will try to remove the Regular part and see if that works out.

Comment: Which font is it? Because some fonts do not support various weights,
i.e. said font may only have 500 support, or 700, etc.

Comment: I use PensumPro

Comment: It is really beautiful. Unfortunately, it is sold separately. Each font file yields one font weight only. What fontWeight does is calling the corresponding font member contained in the font file.

Comment: How can I check which fonts support which weights/styles? Is it possible to print the available options with console.log(...) in react-native?

Comment: I do not believe that is possible, nor is it necessary. You can google it and check each font's website.
[Pensum Pro](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typemates/pensum-pro/)

Comment: In my case I do have the bold version, but I would like to use it as a fontWeight, not as a separate fontFamily. Is that possible?

Comment: It might be possible, but that would take a font editing tool. I might have found a workaround in this other question: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-add-multiple-font-files-for-the-same-font)