# How to match the font generated in web with adobe ilustrator font?

Tags: php, svg

I have svg file which is generated through php but it doesnt contain the font which is having  in the adobe illustrator application.

Example: font-family: 'Twine'

```
<text fill="#000000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="175" y="131" text-anchor="left" font-size="90.75" font-family="Twine" data-textcurve="0" data-itemzoom="1 1">Hello</text>
```

But when i open the same file in adobe illustrator it is having the font-family name as 'aaa Twine'. How to fix the font-family

In my fonts folder I have ttf,woff,png file of

```
/data/fonts/aaatwine.ttf
/data/fonts/aaaTwine.woff
/data/fonts/Twine.png
```

Comment: You will need to load the font as a web font using `@font-face`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-add-multiple-font-files-for-the-same-font/2436830#2436830. Also related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/how-do-i-use-a-custom-font-in-an-svg-image-on-my-site

Comment: If the font family name is "aaa Twine" you should call it like that in your html too.

Comment: Once you got sure that you have the right name, make sure the font is served on the webpage, like @Terry suggests. Also beware, if you see it on AI, that means you got the font installed, so even if you do not take those steps you will see it, but not others looking at the picture.