# Varying Weight and Style in @Font-Face declaration not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have done quite a bit of research at this point on the usage of @font-face, and am familiar with some of the challenges, but have nonetheless decided that I wanted to use it for my application.  However, for some reason completely unknown to me, the browser is not loading the expected font-face.

I have a CSS file with declarations as follows: Note that the "!important" was me messing around with things, it did not appear to have any effect.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf");
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Black.ttf");
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf");
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

.cerberus-body {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-family: roboto;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the structure of my web:

[Web Directory Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd1Jo.png)

As you can see from the screenshot the src paths on the font-face declarations match up with what I have in my directory, and I have verified they are reachable from my deployed site.

The body elem of my page has the following:

```
<body class="cerberus-body"></body>
```

I have verified in dev console that the styles and declaration are working as expected.

Given all of that- here is what I see in the network tab of my dev console when loading my page: (It shows only Roboto-Black and Roboto-Bold getting loaded)

[Network tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySRpH.png)

And when I inspect an element on the page I see that the styles piece shows a rendered font of Roboto Black:

[Rendered font screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2U7d.png)

Inspecting the Body on the page I see that my styles are reflected as I would expect, and the css class is getting honored:

[CSS inspect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sDZB.png)

At this point, I'm really at a loss here.  I could use any help or direction on where to go next troubleshooting this.  I'm at the point where I think it's likely I'm going to give up on the custom font, but this is a last-ditch attempt to save my dignity.

Given that the fonts don't appear to be loading at all through the network tab, I must be missing something with how the rendering engine determines what font faces to lazy load. Beyond that, I'm at a loss.

**Update**

After reading through another question supplied in the comments by Pete, I read that some of the commenters recommended changing the order with which the font-face rules are defined.  I flipped the order of my rules and sure enough, the font rendered as expected.

I'm hesitant to close the question though, as I have no clue why this works and would like to understand the underlying implementation.

For posterity- my new declarations

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf");
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Black.ttf");
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf");
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "roboto";
    src: url("../../Content/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-add-multiple-font-files-for-the-same-font

Comment: Thanks for the response, Pete.  I read through that and I _think_ that the recommended answer actually reflects the approach I have taken. (using multiple font-face declarations).  It further compounds my confusion as to why my solution doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Some of them suggested changing the order of declarations - might help?

Comment: You are right, I did see that.  The way I read it, it appears that they suggest having the bold/variant declarations at the end, which I do.  I will try to flip the order and see if that works though!

Comment: Welp, Pete.  Changing the order worked, but I have no idea why.  I'm going to leave the question open for a bit, in hopes that someone explains why that made a difference.  But- seriously thanks for responding. I was messing around with this for quite a while and was quite frustrated.

Comment: Very weird!  Glad you got it sorted, I hate stuff like that where there is no clear reason for it to work!