# @font-face - Using multiple files for one font

Tags: html, css

It seems this question has been asked numerous time already (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-add-multiple-font-files-for-the-same-font/2436830#2436830)). But my issue does not seem to be resolved with the answers provided.

I am attempting to use multiple files for a single font. Each file is for a different style - italics, bold. I have attempted the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: matrix;
    src: url('../fonts/chris-simpkins_hack/Hack-Regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: matrix;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('../fonts/chris-simpkins_hack/Hack-Bold.ttf');
}
```

My HTML contains the following:

```
<h1>Some Text</h1>
<p><b>Some more text that is bold!</b></p>
```

Unexpectedly, all the text outputted on the page is using the "...bold.tff" file. Why is this?

I have been able to achieve this easily and quickly in the past and am unsure as to what is different this time.

Comment: Is the style of h1 bold? If so, both h1 and your bold p will use bold.

Comment: By browser default, h1 use bold text. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Comment: Chris Cousins No. However, interestingly, if I add `font-weight: normal;` to my h1's css. It will resolve the issue. I can not see why all text is bold by default - I checked under my * selector.

Comment: NoobTW Thanks.. I never actually noticed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By browser default, h1 use bold text. See [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) for details.

Simply add `h1{ font-weight: normal;}` to reset this.

If you don't like the default css by browser, you can use some reset.css or [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

> But, normalize.css treat h1 as bold text, too.

Answer (score 0):

create different classes with font face and assign those classes to expected tags

```
@font-face {
    font-family: matrix;
    src: url('../fonts/chris-simpkins_hack/Hack-Regular.ttf');
}


.myh1 {
  font-family : matrix;
  font-weight : 400;
}
.myp {
  font-family: matrix;
  font-weight:700;
}
```

example

```
<h1 class='myh1'>Some Text</h1>
<p class='myp' >Some more text that is bold!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must use `<em></em>` tags for styling because  is deprecated in HTML4
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

Or you try change font-weight: bold; to font-weight: 700; and add this style

```
b { font-weight: 700; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'BrushScriptStdMedium';
src: url('brushscriptstd.eot');
src: local('Brush Script Std'), local('BrushScriptStd'), url('brushscriptstd.woff') 
format('woff'), url('brushscriptstd.ttf') format('truetype');}
.classname{ font:21px bold italic Arial;}
```